# Actualizar valor de una clase dinamica

Tags: jquery

Tengo un tabla que genera una serie de botones dinámicamente donde al presionar uno de ellos me modifica el texto.
El texto se modifica correctamente del botón que modifico, pero no el color ya que se me modifica en todos.

Que problema hay con la clase?
Este es el código php:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $status = $row['register_status'];
        if ($status == "Active") {
            $register_status = '<button class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>';
        }
        else {
            $register_status = '<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status btn-block" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>';
        }
        $data .= '<tr>
                        <td width="1%"><mark>#'.$row['id'].'</mark></td>
                        <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                        <td width="1%">'.$register_status.'</td>
                        <td width="1%">
```

A nivel jQuery tengo lo siguiente:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click('.btn_status', function(e){
  var button = jQuery(e.target);
  if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
          button.data('status', 'Inactive');
          button.html('Inactive');
          //$(".btn_status").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-warning");
        button.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-warning");
        }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
          button.data('status', 'Active');
          button.html('Active');
          //$(".btn_status").removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");
        button.removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");

        }
  });
})
```

Mi estructura de ficheros es la siguientes:

```
index.php: carga de css, scripts, jquery y funciones (onclick)
ajax/readRecords.php: generación de la tabla
js/script.js: funcion onclick
js/jquery.js: jquery
```

El problema es que me modifica el color del botón que selecciono, pero también del resto.
Intuyo que el valor de la clase se pierde...

Que le sucede a removeClass/addClass para que me lo modifique en todos los botones y no unicamente al que presiono?

Comment: tu addClass debe ser para tu objeto button no para la clase '.btn_status' estas afectando a todos los objetos que actualmente tienen esa clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego el ejemplo, puedes ver el resultado dando click en el botón **Ejecutar**, funciona correctamente, ¿Tienes **bootstrap 3 o 4** agregado a tu apicación?, debe estar al inicio de tu html.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn_status" ).on( "click", function() {

   var button = $(this);
   if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
    button.data('status', 'Inactive');
    button.html('Inactive');
    button.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-warning");
   }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
    button.data('status', 'Active');
    button.html('Active');
    button.removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");
   }
   
  });

})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>

<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status btn-block" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>

<button class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>

<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status btn-block" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>

<button class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>

<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status btn-block" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El secreto esta aqui **$(".btn_status" ).on( "click", function() {**, el evento siempre estará activo, aun existan llamadas asincronas ajax.

Comment: si... tengo bootstrap 3 en mi index.php:  ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>```

Comment: ¿El código que envie no funciona?, por que es el mismo que tienes en el código de la pregunta, ¿pudiste probar el ejmplo?, botón **Ejecutar**

Comment: si. tu código funciona. Lo he probado y he añadido otro botón editándolo y también funciona, pero en el mío no. Que podría mirar mas?

Comment: he actualizado el post con la estructura de ficheros

Comment: el orden de los scripts js es muy importante, al inicio deben ir tus **css**, luego el contenido de tu web y al final tus archivos **js(jquery, plugins, etc)** y muy al ultimo, tu script **js** personalizado (tus funciones personales, el script del onlick).

Comment: lo tengo justo como dices: primero el css, luego el contenido ajax y al final por este orden: jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js y script.js

Comment: entonces, ese es el problema, primero se ejecuta el jquery.click en toda tu web, pero luego el contenido en ajax viene sin ese efecto por ser algo asincrono, modificare el código, dame un momento.

Comment: Modifique el script, me informas como te va.

Comment: igual... al hacer un click en cualquier me modifica todos los botones :(

Comment: Fijate bien en mi modificacion, el evento **on** soporta cambios asincronos ajax, el orden es importante. **$(document).ready** debe estar al final de todo.

Comment: si. puse esa función al final del todo y sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: funciona gracias! tenia un problema con la cache...!

Comment: Excelente, añadiendo algo mas de ayuda, puedes cargar el navegador (chrome) con el nuevo cache con control + F5, o entrar a devtools (F12) ir a Network y deshabilitar el check **Disable cache** para evitar el almacenamiento de cache en desarrollo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas removiendo en toda la clase.  Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que hacerlo directamente en el boton que quieres.  Asi:

```
button.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-warning");
```

Comment: actualizado el post. He añadido la linea según el caso, pero sigue coloreando todos los botones a parte del que presiono

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que el problema está en esta línea

`$(".btn_status").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-warning");`

Debería ser así.

`button.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-warning");`

Comment: actualizado el post. He añadido la linea según el caso, pero sigue coloreando todos los botones a parte del que presiono